# Flag and close my own question

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, vote-to-close

Why is it possible to flag and close my own question?

The only realistic usage I could think of is when I see that my question is a duplicate, but it has already got some great answers. So instead of deleting the question, I would vote to close it as a duplicate.

But still, I can't see how flagging my own question would be useful.

Comment: In cases like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15981777/1190388

Comment: Related: [Why can I flag my own question/answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170427)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you:

- Need a moderator for whatever reason (even if not related to the actual post), flagging one of your own posts is the correct course of action.
- Found a duplicate after asking, closing it as a duplicate is the correct course of action (yes, even if it is your own question!)
- Something is wrong, the post is getting vandalised, or you're being vote abused. Flagging is the correct course of action.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a use-case where a flag for your own question can be useful:

So you asked this question, and it got answered and you accepted the answer, but the "old" question is no longer relevant for the "rest of the world".

You will see that you can no longer delete it, so the only way for you to clean this up:

> is to flag it for moderator attention and ask the moderator to delete
>   it.

Probably there are some more use-cases where you need moderator attention...