# Is it better to vote to close your own question or delete it?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, self-delete

In any case with your own question, is it better practice to vote to close it or to delete it if it meets a close reason?

Comment: Depends: sometimes you can't delete because there are answers. In general: deleting is bad, specially if you have multiple deleted low scoring posts.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170427/why-can-i-flag-my-own-question-answer and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176386/flag-and-close-my-own-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I try to avoid deleting my questions.  If, however, my question is 1), *unanswered*, 2) marked as a duplicate and the proposed duplicate is similar enough to my question, I'll VTC it and delete it (e.g. with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374341/out-of-date-winter-bash-app-description) bug report, which had an exact duplicate, and was closed/deleted by me.  10K only.)  Otherwise, I try not to close or delete my questions.  If one of my posts needs deleting or closing, I'll let the community decide (unless it's blatantly obvious) what to do with it, or ask about it in chat.  If you don't agree with the close reason, edit the question and explain why.

Comment: why VTC and then delete? And not just delete?

Comment: @Vickel Habit, but also to make it... official?  It also means future 10Ks don't have to search through the comments to find the proposed duplicate.  It's just a banner at the top.