# Why would I want to flag my own answer?

Tags: discussion, flags

I found out that I am able to flag my answer on Stack Overflow. But I did not press ok. It appears to be an accepted answer.

I believe there is no use of having this option for my own answer because it seems meaningless. Shouldn't this thing be disabled for my own answer? I don't know how this is useful. How could flagging your own posts be useful?

Comment: Simple: to contact a moderator for help. Same thing *all* flags are used for.

Answer (score 13):

No it should not be disabled. Just because you can't think of a use right now doesn't mean there aren't potential uses. Here are a couple scenarios where it can be useful:

- Somebody has edited your post either maliciously or in error and you want a moderator to review the situation. This is the right way to avoid an edit war if the other editor keeps editing.
- Your post was deleted but you have edited it and want a review to get it undeleted.
- Your answer has been selected as accepted but you later find it to be in error and want to delete it. You don't have permission to remove accepted answers but a moderator could do this for you if you give them a reason.
- You discover your post contains sensitive information that needs to be removed from even the revision history.
- You decide another site would be a more appropriate host for your question and would like a moderator to migrate it.

There are undoubtedly other uses as well, but suffice it to say there are legitimate reasons to flag your own posts for moderator attention.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say someone keeps editing your answer inappropriately. Instead of going the roll-back war way, you could issue a flag asking a moderator to look into the situation. And that's just one example.

In that case you're not pointing out problems with yourself, but problems with your post that only a moderator can really handle. 
Flags are useful, even on your own content.